# How do I use sh in Jenkins Global library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am creating my own global library for Jenkins, which I have [hosted on github](https://github.com/JoSSte/JenkinsGlobalLibraries), and to simplify some run-of-the-mill tasks, I wanted to add a function that returns the GIT tag.

Therefore I created something like this:

```
    class Myclass{
      static String getGitTag() {
        return "${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1').trim()}"
      }
    }
```

... which results in this error:

> No signature of method: static com.stevnsvig.jenkins.release.ReleaseUtil.sh()

So I'm left with two questions:

1. Is the solution to import the `sh()` library that Jenkins' groovy flavor obviously already has imported? (and if so how)
2. What is the best practice here? I am wondering why there isn't a `GIT_TAG` global variable when you use declarative pipelines, and something like this should (in my opinion) be easy as pie.

### EDIT #1:

```
    static String getGitTag() {
        stdout = script.sh(script: "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1", returnStdout: true)
        return stdout.trim()
    }
```

produces a similar error:

> No signature of method: static com.stevnsvig.jenkins.release.ReleaseUtil.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[returnStdout:true, script:git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1]]

### EDIT #2:

```
   static String getGitTag() {
        def stdout = "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1".execute()
        return stdout.in.text
    }
```

completes, but the output is blank. Running the same command with `pwd` returns `/` which indicaes that the environment is not set, which makes sense, since all the commands running under Jenkins are designed to rununder pipelines

### EDIT #3:

I went hunting for the import. Stumbled across the Jenkins CI project on github and started searching the many repositories. [Found a promising one](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/durable_task/ShellStep.java)... and put a file called `pwd.groovy` in `/vars` with this content:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.ShellStep


    static String getPWD() {
        def ret = ShellStep.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1").trim()
        echo "currently in ${ret}"
    }
```

The error I got is a variation of the same. I guess since itsa plugin, the definition is different...

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.ShellStep.sh() is applicable ...

Comment: Please share your project folder & file structure and the source code of the file which define the `getGitTag()`

Comment: @yong The link at the top [a global library for Jenkins](https://github.com/JoSSte/JenkinsGlobalLibraries) links to all the source

Comment: You will indeed need to import the Pipeline Steps library for the definition of `sh` in your class. Additionally, all three of your attempts have various issues, but the second is closest to being correct, so continue with that attempt after importing.

Comment: Alternatively you could define this method as a global var instead of a global library class member, and then you could avoid the import issue altogether. This method seems more than straightforward enough to justify being a global var instead.

Comment: @MattSchuchard didn't have much luck unfortunately...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1) Use Groovy `execute` to run cmd and get its output as below

```
tag = "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1".execute().text
```

Option 2) Use Jenkins pipeline step `sh`.

One concept need to get clear: the context of `sh is global function` is when `sh` used **directly** inside Jenkinsfile.

In your case, `sh` is used outside the Jenkinsfile. To make better understand I give an example Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
 
  stages('foo') {
    steps {
       sh 'pwd' 
       // In above sh step, there is an implicit `this` which represents the 
       // global object for Jenkinsfile, you can image  sh 'pwd'  to this.sh 'pwd'
       // 
       // Thus if you want to use `sh` outside Jenkinsfile, you must pass down the
       // implicit `this` into the file where you used `sh`
    }
  }
}
```

To address your issue

```
// ReleaseUtil.groovy

static String getGitTag(steps) {
   // here `steps` is the global object for Jenkinsfile
   // you can use other pipeline step here by `steps`

   steps.echo 'test use pipeline echo outside Jenkinsfile'

   steps.withCredentials([steps.string(credentialsId: 'git_hub_auth', variable: 'GIT_AUTH_TOKEN')]) {
      steps.echo '....'
      steps.sh '....'
   }

   
   return  steps.sh(returnStdout: true, script:"git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1").trim()
}
```

```
// Jenkinsfile

import com.stevnsvig.jenkins.release.ReleaseUtil

pipeline {
 
  stages('foo') {
    steps {
       ReleaseUtil.getGitTag(this)
    }
  }
}
```